# How to backup mysql database every 5 miniutes automatically

Tags: mysql

I want to know ,how to backup **database**
 every 5 minutes automatically.

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > mydb_backup.sql
```

Comment: If you are in a linux environment, you can make use of a cron job.

Comment: put this command in a shell script and then create a crontab entry for it to run every 5 minutes. Btw , curious enough, have you calculated the size of DB which you want to backup, because there will be 2880 backups every day

Comment: Use the cron tab for this. There you can configure your backup command to be run every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Make schedule db back up >>

1. make directory with - `sudo mkdir db_backup`
2. create shell script file named backup_db.sh in  /var/www/dir_name
   and add this

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   mysqldump -u user -p'password' db_name > /var/www/dir_name/db_backup/db_$( date +"%Y_%m_%d" ).sql
   ```
3. Give the adequate permission to the that sh file with - `chmod 700
       backup_db.sh`
4. and then create a cron with - `crontab -e` and add this `*/5 * * * *
   /var/www/dir_name/backup_db.sh` (Execute a cron job every 5 minutes)